# Calculating likely journey matches based upon their physical locations

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need your help. I have a database table called 'journeys' which contains **(fromlat, fromlng, tolat, tolng)** and I also have another table called 'cityPostcodes' which contains **(postcode, lat, lng)**.

Users can search journeys by just entering 'from postcode' and 'to postcode'. After mapping these postcodes to their actual physical locations, I want to calculate likely journey matches based upon these postcodes.

What I am struggling is, how to check if two journeys are heading to the same direction? for example, the journey searched by the user and those in the '`journeys`' table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like the [geospatial extension for PHP](https://pecl.php.net/package/geospatial) to calculate the cardinal direction of the from/to lat/long coordinates to see if they head in the same cardinal direction.

You would need an origin latitude/longitude set of coordinates and a destination lat/long for each journey. You can then using something like [the Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) or [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) to calculate distince and derive the cardinal North/South/East/West direction of the line segments along the ellipsoid.